# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: json

For several hours now I have been crazily trying to get and display json data externally using JSON.parse  but am having this error below

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at index.html:10**

Here is my code and effort so far. can somebody help me fix the issue. I will appreciate

```
 var test = JSON.parse ('data.json');
    console.log(test);

alert(test);





/*
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'data.json');

ourRequest.onload = function(){
    var ourData  = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    console.log(ourData);
 console.log(ourData[0]);
alert(ourData);
};
ourRequest.send();
*/


</script>
```

data.json

```
{
        name: "Sample Test",
        description: "This is a sample test paper to demonstrate the ReactJS UI design by components.",
        passCutoff: 0.33,       
        applyNegativeMarking: false,
        time: 1,
        questions: [
            {
            no: "1",
            qtext:"California is in which part of USA?",
            options:[
                {text:"East"},
                {text:"Mid"},
                {text:"West"},
                {text:"South"}
            ],
            ans:"West",
            marks: 3
        },
        {
            no: "2",
            qtext:"Who is Prime Minister of India?",
            options:[
                {text:"Sonia Gandhi"},
                {text:"Narendra Modi"},
                {text:"Manmohan Singh"},
                {text:"Rahul Gandhi"}
            ],
            ans:"Narendra Modi",
            marks: 2
        },
        {
            no: "3",
            qtext:"Which of the following is most popular Search Engine Company?",
            options:[
                {text:"Microsoft"},
                {text:"Facebook"},
                {text:"Google"},
                {text:"Yahoo"}
            ],
            ans:"Google",
            marks: 1
        },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: You can not use `JONS.parse` to get data from server.

Comment: @FerhadOthman. please what do i do

Comment: Check the example below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example which may help you:

```
function loadJSON() {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var data=JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
        data=JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
    }
  };
  http.open("GET", "data.json", true);
  http.send();
}
loadJSON()
```

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is asynchronous so you should do:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
});
```